# How the canonical symplectic form acts

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, multilinear-algebra, symplectic-geometry

I've read that the canonical symplectic form $\omega$ on $\mathbb R^{2n}$ is given by $$\omega=\sum_{i=1}^n dp_i\wedge dq_i,$$
where $(p_1,\dots,p_n,q_1,\dots,q_n)$ are the coordinates on $\mathbb R^{2n}$.

If I've understood correctly, this means that $\omega$ is a differential 2-form on $\mathbb R^{2n}$, i.e. $$\forall p\in \mathbb R^{2n} \quad\omega_p\in \Lambda^2(T_p\mathbb R^{2n})^*, $$
thus $\omega_p$ is a skew 2-form, so $$\omega_p:T_p\mathbb R^{2n} \times T_p\mathbb R^{2n}\to \mathbb R $$
is bilinear and alternating.

Now, we can put in 1-1 correspondence $T_p\mathbb R^{2n}$ with $\mathbb R^{2n}$, because to every derivation of $T_p\mathbb R^{2n}$ corresponds its direction, which is a vector of $\mathbb R^{2n}$.
So, given $u,v\in \mathbb R^{2n}$, how should I compute $\omega_p(u,v)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With block matrix notation,
where $0_n$ is the $n \times n$ zero matrix and $I_n$ is the $n \times n$ identity matrix,
it's simply the matrix product
$$
\omega_p(u,v)=
(u_1,\dots,u_{2n})
\begin{pmatrix}
0_n & I_n \\ -I_n & 0_n
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
v_1 \\ \vdots \\ v_{2n}
\end{pmatrix}
.
$$
To see this, call the basis vectors
$$
(\partial/\partial p_1,\dots,\partial/\partial p_n,\partial/\partial q_1,\dots,\partial/\partial q_n)
,
$$
and then use
$$
dp_i(\partial/\partial q_j)=0
,\qquad
dp_i(\partial/\partial p_j)=\delta_{ij}$$
(and the similar formulas for $dq_i$) together with the definition of the action of a wedge product:
$$
(\alpha \wedge \beta)(u,v) =
\begin{vmatrix}
\alpha(u) & \alpha(v) \\
\beta(u) & \beta(v)
\end{vmatrix}
.
$$

Comment: How can I compute the matrix?

Comment: What do you mean? It's just a matrix of zeros and ones, so there's not much to compute...

Comment: No, I mean, why is that the matrix associated to the bilinear form $\omega_p$? I know that its coefficients are given by $\omega_p(e_i,e_j)$. right? So how can I compute $\omega_p(e_i,e_j)$?

Comment: Oh, I see! I added some more explanation to the answer.

Comment: Perfect!  I missed the action of the wedge product.